# Is it possible for Non booting Win OS Sony Laptop to Boot Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, bootloader

I have a Sony Vaio laptop that won't boot windows with an AMD Vision CPU, can I install Ubuntu to the SATA drive and boot it ?

I apologize in advance if this sounds dumb. My kid killed windows on it and it won't boot up, but we were able to remove the hard-drive and put it in a portable USB powered case. Formated drive so its clean. We don't want windows back. We use a debian OS on a Pi zero that works just fine for what school projects are needed and Ubuntu seems like a good alternative on the POS windows comp.

Comment: The only one that can tell us this is the person that boots that system up with a live dvd... and it is likely that that will *you*. No harm can come from just booting up a live dvd so go for it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you surely can. You can live boot Ubuntu through a Ubuntu stick or an Ubuntu DVD. You can use a tool like [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) to create a bootable USB drive.

If you wish, you can take the next step and install Ubuntu. You can find the instructions to do so [here](https://builtvisible.com/the-ubuntu-installation-guide/).